# How to configure Netgear DGN2000 as a wireless repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater

I want my Netgear N300 DGN2000 router work as a wireless repeater. The parent would be a D-Link DIR-600 router. Is this possible?

I've been searching but all I've found is how to set up two or more Netgear routers. I just want to extend the range of my wireless internet connection.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Should this not be on superuser?

Comment: @FalconKirtaran Yes, and at the rate you're going, it won't be long before you'll be able to vote to move questions like this that are off-topic.  In the meantime, you can flag it for moderator attention w/ a note of where you think it should belong.